# Raspberry Pi Zero Using 5v Pins to power Circuit

Tags: raspbian, gpio, hardware, pi-zero

I have a [motozero](https://thepihut.com/products/motozero) where I need to connect to a power supply.Can I use the 5v pins from raspberry pi zero as a power source? If so what pins numbers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Power Raspberry Pi Zero W through GPIO](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/74689/power-raspberry-pi-zero-w-through-gpio)

Comment: @Irfan I think this question has it the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 5V pins as a power source.  They can provide anything left over from the input power feed not used by the Pi itself.  You will have to check to see if there is enough left over to power your device.

You use a ground pin and a 5V pin.  Typically the ground pin will be connected to where you would connect the -ve of a battery and the 5V pin to where you would connect the +ve of a battery.

You can use any ground pin and 5V pin you choose.

See https://pinout.xyz/