# Separating power in Pi Zero when using the Pi as a HID that must be working without shuting down

Tags: pi-zero-w, power-supply, hid

I asked an AI:

> When you use raspberry pi zero w as a HID, is it necessary to connect the pi to a machine via a single micro usb cable, for the power and the data connectivity? Does that mean that when the machine shuts down the connected pi also gets shut down? I was planning to use the pi as a HID when the machine is showing a bios boot menu right after a reboot.

And the AI responds:

> Yes, when using a Raspberry Pi Zero W as a Human Interface Device (HID), it is necessary to connect it to a machine via a single micro USB cable for both power and data connectivity. This is because the Raspberry Pi Zero W does not have built-in wireless capabilities and requires a wired connection for communication.

> If the machine to which the Raspberry Pi Zero W is connected shuts down, the Raspberry Pi Zero W will also lose power and shut down as well, as it is powered through the micro USB cable. This means that if you're planning to use the Raspberry Pi Zero W as a HID during the BIOS boot menu right after a reboot, you will need to ensure that the machine remains powered on during that time for the Raspberry Pi Zero W to continue functioning as a HID.

> This could involve using a separate power source, such as a USB power bank, to power the Raspberry Pi Zero W independently of the machine, or finding a way to keep the machine powered on during the BIOS boot menu.

Now, he said "power the Raspberry Pi Zero W independently of the machine" but how is that possible? Thanks.

Comment: `but how is that possible?.` Have you asked the 'AI'?

Comment: If you choose to rely on alleged AI (which quite patently doesn't understand your question or you asked the wrong question) that is your problem. Ask your OWN question not asking us to respond to rubbish. You claim to have a Pi Zero.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Power Raspberry Pi Zero W through GPIO](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/74689/power-raspberry-pi-zero-w-through-gpio)

Comment: With quick googling I came across this link, which may be a good start for you to understand what are the options powering Pi Zero
https://www.makeuseof.com/raspberry-pi-power-methods/

Comment: @Dirk Yes and the AI couldn't resolve the question. Sorry for that I didn't explicitly mention it.

Comment: @Vadim I think yes. Thanks.

Comment: A neural net deriived AI has no concept of truth, it is just making things up that *appear to be* the product of rational thought.  Here's a simple fact check: *"This is because the Raspberry Pi Zero W does not have built-in wireless capabilities"* -> But the Zero W **is the wifi version of the Zero.** However it is on the right track WRT the power state issue. If you are okay doing this via a reboot, I think most computers will leave the USB power on during that process (but I could be completely wrong about that, I guess it is easy enough to check).